# Could spreadtab save state to file between compilations?

Tags: spreadtab

I recently started using the `spreadtab` package. This generally works well, but it has the following limitation, and probably other similar ones.

If one is tagging a cell (using `tag`), and then wants to reference the tagged value (using `value`), the `tag` needs to precede the `value` in the file. If `value` precedes `tag` it will not work.

TeX handles such things by saving state to a file, normally an `aux` file. But it seems the author chose not to go that route.

I was wondering if there were technical difficulties in implementing an approach like that, or if it was simply a matter of the author's preferences.

Among other benefits, this would also obviate the distinction between local and global tagging.

To illustrate the tagging issue, see

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  value(foo)\\
\end{spreadtab}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  tag(foo)1\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `pdflatex` using `spreadsheet` 0.5, this gives the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> 
Package \ST@package@name 
                                   Warning: The tag "\detokenize \expandafte...
l.7 \end{spreadtab}
                   
?
```

If the `tag` is defined in a `spreadtab` which is inside a group, that requires special handling to be visible - one has to make the `tag` global. But if one was to save state to file that should not be necessary either.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\makeatletter
\def\ST@package@name{spreadtab}                               
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  tag(foo)1\\
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{foo}                                                                                                                            
\endgroup

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  value(foo)\\
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

With @touhami's correction, this gives the warning

```
Package spreadtab Warning: The tag "foo" does not exists, have you defined it? 
on input line 23.
```

Comment: By the way, the error chowen here is unrelated it just a forgotten definition. One can add `\makeatletter\def\ST@package@name{spreadtab}\makeatother`.

Comment: @touhami Can you elaborate? A forgotten definition by who?

Comment: FaheemMitha by the package's author, I suppose. If you add the line suggested by @touhami after loading the package, you'll see the real error: `lilla.tex|9 warning| Package spreadtab Warning: The tag "foo" does not exists, have you defined it? on input line 9.`  [sic]

Comment: @Rmano. Oh, so I should submit a bug report? I tried to register for the custom site on which the bug tracker is. It said I needed to get permission, but I never heard anything after that. I'll check the site again, and if it is still not working, I'll send an email. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. There is a line `\PackageWarning\ST@package@name{The tag "\detokenize\expandafter{#1}" does not exists, have you defined it?}` in `spreadtab.sty` which gets called. But `\ST@package@name`is never actually defined. And it should be "exist".

Comment: I have an account on framagit, so I created it: https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/spreadtab/-/issues/3

Comment: Thanks @Rmano. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the values to the aux file, this warns on the first pass that the tag is not defined, but on the second pass it is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\makeatletter
\def\ST@package@name{spreadtab}

\def\STsave#1{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\global\string\@namedef{\string\detokenize{ST@celltag@\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}}%
   {\csname ST@celltag@\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\endcsname}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  value(foo)\\
\end{spreadtab}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c}}
  tag(foo)1\\
\end{spreadtab}
\STsave{foo}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not expecting a solution to this. I thought I would just get some comments. But this fixes the two examples above (I just added one.) Two questions. One, is this a general solution, and if so, why didn't the author do it this way before? And two, shouldn't this `\STsave` be part of the `tag` function? That way it would be handled automatically.

Comment: @FaheemMitha you have to ask the author "Why" questions but I thought I saw that tag() was handled in a pre-parse and didn't expand to anything in the cell, you can not write to a file as an expandable operation so writing at that point may affect spacing or break things completely. But not sure about that, I don't know the package at all.

Comment: also you'd probably have to ban using the same tag name in two tables as this would just save teh value of the last one and make it available from the start of the docuemnt which would be well defined but weird.